# Scraping data from web imbedded interactive graph

Tags: python, web-scraping, graphics, request

I'm trying to retrieve data from a website's interactive graph using the underlying API that sends data from the server to the web browser but I'm no sure what I'm doing nor if this approach can work. The website is [located here](https://ember-climate.org/data/data-tools/carbon-price-viewer/) and the page only contains the grap that holds the data I'm trying to pull.

What I've tried so far:

- After inspecting the element I found the request url:

```
    url ='https://ember-data-api-scg3n.ondigitalocean.app/ember.json?sql=select+variable%2C+year%2C+share_of_generation_pct+from+generation_yearly+where+variable+in+%28%27Clean%27%2C+%27Coal%27%29+and+country_or_region%3D%27World%27&_shape=array'
```

- Pulled the cookies:

```
    res = r.get(url)
    cookies = res.cookies
```

- Tried to retreive data using:

```
res_post = r.post(url, data={'method':'POST'}, cookies=cookies,
headers={'user-agent':user_agent})
```

However I get  `<Response [405]>`

Can you help ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why `POST` and not `GET`?

Comment: tried both actually

Comment: Both result in a `405`?

Comment: yep, sounds like i don't have the rights either way

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to get that data (this was tested in a Jupyter notebook, so replace `display` with `print` if using a different IDE):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get("https://ember-data-api-scg3n.ondigitalocean.app/ember.json?sql=select variable, year, share_of_generation_pct from generation_yearly where variable in ('Clean', 'Coal') and country_or_region='World'&_shape=array", headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json())
display(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    variable    year    share_of_generation_pct
0   Clean   2000    35.82
1   Coal    2000    38.20
2   Clean   2001    35.34
3   Coal    2001    38.17
4   Clean   2002    34.75
5   Coal    2002    38.49
6   Clean   2003    33.56
7   Coal    2003    39.64
8   Clean   2004    33.99
9   Coal    2004    39.18
10  Clean   2005    33.53
11  Coal    2005    39.64
12  Clean   2006    33.26
13  Coal    2006    40.28
14  Clean   2007    32.02
15  Coal    2007    40.98
16  Clean   2008    32.77
17  Coal    2008    40.32
18  Clean   2009    33.19
19  Coal    2009    39.96
20  Clean   2010    32.80
21  Coal    2010    39.92
22  Clean   2011    32.18
23  Coal    2011    40.70
24  Clean   2012    32.09
25  Coal    2012    39.95
26  Clean   2013    32.64
27  Coal    2013    40.80
28  Clean   2014    33.16
29  Coal    2014    40.54
30  Clean   2015    33.87
31  Coal    2015    38.72
32  Clean   2016    34.55
33  Coal    2016    37.98
34  Clean   2017    35.18
35  Coal    2017    38.04
36  Clean   2018    35.60
37  Coal    2018    38.04
38  Clean   2019    36.91
39  Coal    2019    36.72
40  Clean   2020    38.48
41  Coal    2020    35.37
42  Clean   2021    38.13
43  Coal    2021    36.26
44  Clean   2022    39.00
45  Coal    2022    35.76
```

Requests documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), and for pandas, go [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/)